# How to feed information to internal testers of iOS app

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, testflight

I am developing an iOS app, that is currently in internal testing phase. The internal testers receive updates of my product through Apple's **Testflight**. Is it possible to add a description of sorts that would direct my testers with information about the changes done on a certain build?

On the organizer windows from Xcode, there is a build description field, but it seems that the information isn't sent along-side the app itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wanna give some additional info for testers you can do it following https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/BetaTestingTheApp.html > **Add or Edit Metadata for your Prerelease App**

> If you would like to add or make changes to the Test Information, such
>   as What to Test or Description, you can do so at any time by viewing
>   your build from the Activity pane.
>
> 1. Open the App Details page, as described in Creating an iTunes Connect
>      Record for an App.
> 2. Click Activity.
> 3. Select All Builds for the platform of the build you want to edit.
> 4. Click the build number you want to test.
> 5. On Test Information, provide information for your testers such as What to Test, App Description, your feedback email address, and URLs. You will also provide information for App Review in the Beta App Review Information section, including contact information, demo account information, and any special notes on the build. Please note that this information is specific to Beta App Review and is not the same as the App Review contact information you provide when submitting your App Store version.

Comment: Perfect!
It would be much better if this was possible through xcode directly.

Comment: I don't think this metadata feeds through to internal testers